# maven-antrun-plugin sshexec with cygwin can not find my keyfile, no matter which format I use

Tags: maven, cygwin, ssh-keys, maven-antrun-plugin

no matter which keyfile format I use - forward slashes, backward slashes, cygwin format, maven-antrun-plugin sshexec can not find my keyfile, but IT'S THERE.
what am I doing wrong?
`<sshexec username="cloudera" keyfile="C:\Users\gaga\.ssh\id_rsa" host="myhost" command="bla"/>`